# Follow a .lnk with samba

Tags: samba, symbolic-link

I'm trying to access some file on my company's local network. The file I was looking for appears to be a Windows shortcut (`.lnk`) and, of course, I can't follow it from my Ubuntu.

I didn't find any option with smbclient to be able to access what's behind the link. Does anyone have an idea on how to get there?

I don't need Samba to follow the link, I just need to know where it goes, so I can access the file directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either

1. Try opening the file using an editor (like gedit) and see if it helps you see the link's target.
2. Use [`lnkforward`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/en/man1/lnkforward.1.html) (Kubuntu Only)
3. Use Strings
   `strings filename.lnk`
   Gives out lots of information, including the target location.

---

#### Example

```
[1940][DC++]$ strings Uninstall.lnk 
home
nemo
.wine
drive_c
Program Files
DC++
uninstall.exe
C:\Program Files\DC++\uninstall.exe
```

Comment: The editor works, it's not very user-friendly but one can read the important informations anyway. I didn't try `lnkforward`. `strings` is exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot!